# clang fatal error: fatal error: 'stdint.h' file not found

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, clang, llvm-clang

Getting clang error:

`fatal error: 'stdint.h' file not found`

I have extracted the exact compilation command from makefile which is throwing the above error:

`clang -MD -MP -std=c99 -include sys/cdefs.h -Wall -O2 -target armv6k-none-eabi -mfloat-abi=soft -m32 -emit-llvm -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc -Wno-c11-extensions  -I/Path/To/Project/include -I/Path/To/Project/genconfig  -c folder1/abc.c -o folder1/abc.bc`

```
somefile.h:50: fatal error: 'stdint.h' file not found
#  include <stdint.h>
           ^
```

The `somefile.h` is just a normal file inside the project.
Would like to know why the above `clang` command is generating the mentioned compilation error.
In addition to the above main question, Anyone please explain what is this `.bc` file - see at the end of command? In general few words about this llvm-clang concept. I would Highly appreciate it.

I have to compile without using standard headers. So `-nostdinc` option should be present in the command. Actually I am compiling some kernel (small version) which is not suppose to use standard includes or libs.

My system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: `-nostdinc` perhaps?

Comment: @kaylum. OK What is the reasoning behind it? What exactly does `-nostdinc` do?

Comment: Perhaps read [the manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-nostdinc)? "Do not search the standard system directories or compiler builtin directories for include files."

Comment: @kaylum. `-nostdinc` option is already present in the clang command. See my post. :)

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's the problem.

Comment: Did you read the linked manual at all? Or the part that Kaylum cited? Isn't that perfectly matching what you experience?

Comment: But actually I was thinking I have to compile without using standard headers. So `-nostdinc` option should be present in the command. Actually I am compiling some kernel (small version) which is not suppose to use standard includes or libs.

Comment: You tell the compiler not to include standard headers and then you want to use a standard header. How does that go together?

Comment: You want to include `stdint.h` which is a standard header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215272/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-needsomeluck).

Comment: I want to point out that its related to `newlib` ... Usually kernel code or any code which is kind of bare metal - uses headers from `newlib` . `newlib` contains headers like stdint.h. I wanted someone to elaborate more on this.